# syntax error in mariaDB that i cannot find

Tags: python, mariadb

i am writing a code to write my gps variables in my database but i get this error everytime i run it:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Long, Status) VALUES (1, 50.821139333333335, 3.2815086666666664, 'Eind')' at line 1

the database has an id that is auto incremented and then the following values i'm trying to add, no clue what's going wrong. maybe you guys have an idea

database.py:

```py
@staticmethod
def execute_sql(sqlQuery, params=None):
    result = None
    db, cursor = Database.__open_connection()
    try:
        cursor.execute(sqlQuery, params)
        db.commit()
        result = cursor.lastrowid
    except connector.Error as error:
        db.rollback()
        result = None
        print(f"Error: Data not stored.{error.msg}")
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
        return result
```

datarepository.py:

```py
@staticmethod
def create_gps(RouteID, Lat, Long, Status):
    sql = "INSERT INTO gps (RouteID, Lat, Long, Status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
    params = [RouteID, Lat, Long, Status]
    return Database.execute_sql(sql, params)
```

app.py:

```py
@socketio.on('F2B_GPS')
def gps_aan(toggle, status):
    while(toggle != 1):
        port = "/dev/serial0"
        ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5)
        dataout = pynmea2.NMEAStreamReader()
        newdata = ser.readline()
        if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
            newdata = newdata.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
        if newdata[0:6] == "$GPRMC":
            newmsg = pynmea2.parse(newdata)
            lat = newmsg.latitude
            lng = newmsg.longitude
            gps = "Latitude=" + str(lat) + "and Longitude=" + str(lng)
            print(gps)
            DataRepository.create_gps(1,lat,lng, status)
            print("added")
            toggle = 1
```

Thanks to anyone replying :)

Answer (score 0):

ok i found it you cant use Long since that screws it up in mysql so i had to change it to longitude